# base object instantiated by a derivative class using derivative class's methods

Tags: c++, class, oop, radix, derivative

Since I'm very unfamiliar with OOP, I decided to change that and write my first "class-based" project. I ran into an issue, that I'm not sure how to explain with words (the question title is disastrous, I know), so I'll just paste the code that should make my problem clear

```
void basecheck() {
    std::cout << "base check" << std::endl;
}

void derivativecheck() {
    std::cout << "derivative check" << std::endl;
}

class mybase {
public:
    mybase() {
        std::cout << "base constructor" << std::endl;
        check = basecheck;
    }
    void (*check)();
};

class myderivative : public mybase {
public:
    myderivative() {
        std::cout << "derivative constructor" << std::endl;
        check = derivativecheck;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::list<mybase> mylist;
    mylist.push_back(myderivative());
    mylist.front().check();
    return 0;
}
```

This works the way I intended (mylist.front().check() prints out "derivative check"), but I'd rather refrain from using function pointers if it's possible (they don't seem very OOP-ish and I wanna learn it instead of using dirty hacks). However, I have absolutely no idea how to get rid of them and keep the current functionality, as:

- if I make "check" a purely virtual function, then I can no longer declare a list of "mybase" type,
- if I try to override check() in the derivative class, then calling mylist.front().check() will print out mybase's check() rather than myderivative's check(),
- if I remove the base class's function body, then the code won't compile,

I have no idea what else to try and I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: `std::list<mybase>` stores instances of `mybase`, never instances of `myderivative`. If you want a collection of objects of various types derived from `mybase`, you need a container of (possibly smart) `mybase` pointers. See also: [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The smart pointers solution works, thanks for the assistance!